# How to use LazyLoading with EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm trying to use EntityManagerFactory like this:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Override
public User getByID(long id) {
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(Session.class);       
    return (User) session.createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.idEq(id)).uniqueResult();
}

...
}
```

But I've got an error:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Hibernate cannot unwrap EntityManagerFactory as 'org.hibernate.Session'

Comment: either you're using JPA or Hibernate, time to choose. There is no point in using a (deprecated) HIbernate API when JPA criteria does that. An EMF gives access to the EntityManager.

Comment: @Neil Stockton, thanks! It explains why I've got "no proxy"... So in other words, if I have huge data base and I don't want to loose all my memory using Fetch.Eager, entity manager is unsuitable?